# Using multiple rewrite rules .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I made the switch of my website from http to https. Now, I want to 301 redirect all http content to https.

I want to use this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

The issue is I also have another rule already in place which redirects all non-www pages to www ones.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [last,redirect=301]
```

How can I combine it so whatever link users write (http non-www ; http www ; https non-www) all redirect to https://www.example.com

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this single rule to add `www` and `http->https` in single rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

This rule should be kept just below `RewriteEngine` line and make sure to clear your browser cache when testing this change.